# Steps to creating 3 plane equations with 3 lines of intersection

Tags: vectors

I was wondering if anyone can give me pointers on to how to mathematically create 3 plane equations that meet in 3 lines. In other words, each plane intersects one another in a straight line (so it sort of makes a triangle in a way)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'three lines'? I can read that in two ways, and so give two different conclusions.

Comment: I edited my question hoping it's more clear. I'm basically trying to get each plane to intersects one another in a straight line, meaning their normals are not collinear nor coplanar, and that n3 = sn1 + tn2 but D3≠sD1 + tD2

Comment: If one normal is a linear combination of the other two, then by definition these three vectors are coplanar.

Comment: you're right, I was looking at another question. So if we know the normals are coplanar, but again n3 = sn1 + tn2 but D3≠sD1 + tD2, what approach can I take to creating these 3 equations?

Comment: What are $\{D_1,D_2,D_3\}$ here? Not recognizing the notation.

Comment: the constant in the scalar equation Ax+By+Cz+D=0

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose you take the case where all three lines point up, and then consider the normal vectors for the three planes. What do you notice? How would you represent this condition?

Comment: would the normal of the planes be perpendicular to the line?

Comment: Considering that any one of the lines lie in two of the planes, that line had better be perpendicular to their normals. @Louzzy56

Comment: ok, and that means all I have to do is choose a line, find a vector that's dot product with the line's normal is zero, find a point on the line in which they intersect, formulate one plane equation, then just formulate 2 other equations that are coplanar to the first and I'm good?

Comment: That description sounds a bit confused. I suggest trying to put that together in a bit more length, and put it out as an answer so we can give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out (somewhat) but I might still have a few loose ends:

Step 1: Create an equation of a line. This will be used as reference.

Step 2: Find the direction vector of the line.

Step 3: Using the normal of the line and another vector, *a*, (which you must create yourself), ensure that the dot product equals to zero. This will, thus, mean that you've found the normal of a plane.

Step 4: Find a point on the line.

Step 5: Using the point of the line and vector a (normal of plane 1), you can create your first plane equation

Step 6: Since the normal of one plane is a linear combination of the other two, find two other noramls and create another 2 plane equations

I just don't think it's possible to use the same point on the line so I'm stuck.

Comment: Ok. Some comments: What do you mean by the "normal" of the line? The tangent vector of the line can be specified, but there's no unique vector which is perpendicular to it. (If you meant the tangent vector, your third step becomes clearer.)

Comment: I actually mean direction vector

Comment: That's the same as tangent vector, so we're on the same page. Also, in step 6 you don't actually need to find _two_ other normals. Once you've found a second one in addition to your first, any linear combination of them will do.

Comment: Finally, you're correct that you shouldn't use a point on the same line you started with since then you'd still be on the two planes that you've set up to intersect there. But what if you pick a point which is on one plane but not the other?